# Does g++'s std::list::sort invalidate iterators?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, g++

According to SGI, cplusplus.com, and every other source I've got, the sort() member function of the std::list should not invalidate iterators. However, that doesn't seem to be the case when I run this code (c++11):

```
#include <list>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include "print.hpp"
unsigned int seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
std::default_random_engine generator(seed);
std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int> distribution(1, 1000000000);
auto rng = std::bind(distribution, generator);
// C++11 RNG stuff. Basically, rng() now gives some unsigned int [1, 1000000000]

int main() {
    unsigned int values(0);
    std::cin >> values;           // Determine the size of the list
    std::list<unsigned int> c;
    for (unsigned int n(0); n < values; ++n) {
        c.push_front(rng());
    }
    auto c0(c);
    auto it(c.begin()), it0(c0.begin());
    for (unsigned int n(0); n < 7; ++n) {
        ++it;     // Offset these iterators so I can print 7 values
        ++it0;
    }
    std::cout << "With seed: " << seed << "\n";
    std::cout << "Unsorted list: \n";
    print(c.begin(), c.end()) << "\n";
    print(c.begin(), it) << "\n\n";
    auto t0 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    c0.sort();
    auto d0 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - t0;
    std::cout << "Sorted list: \n";
    print(c0.begin(), c0.end()) << "\n";
    print(c0.begin(), it0) << "\n";  // My own print function, given further below
    std::cout << "Seconds: " << std::chrono::duration<double>(d0).count() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In print.hpp:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class InputIterator>
std::ostream& print(InputIterator begin, const InputIterator& end, 
                    std::ostream& out = std::cout) {
    bool first(true);
    out << "{";
    for (; begin != end; ++begin) {
        if (first) {
            out << (*begin);
            first = false;
        } else {
            out << ", " << (*begin);
        }
    }
    out << "}";
    return out;
}
```

Sample input/output:

```
11
With seed: 3454921017
Unsorted list: 
{625860546, 672762972, 319409064, 8707580, 317964049, 762505303, 756270868, 249266563, 224065083, 843444019, 523600743}
{625860546, 672762972, 319409064, 8707580, 317964049, 762505303, 756270868}

Sorted list: 
{8707580, 224065083, 249266563, 317964049, 319409064, 523600743, 625860546, 672762972, 756270868, 762505303, 843444019}
{8707580, 224065083}
Seconds: 2.7e-05
```

Everything works as expected, except for the printing. It is supposed to show 7 elements, but instead the actual number is fairly haphazard, provided "value" is set to more than 7. Sometimes it gives none, sometimes it gives 1, sometimes 10, sometimes 7, etc.
So, is there something observably wrong with my code, or does this indicate that g++'s std::list (and std::forward_list) is not standards conforming?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sample output added, though it isn't exactly exemplary, since the output changes all the time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The iterators remain valid and still refer to the same elements of the list, *which have been re-ordered*.

So I don't think your code does what you think it does. It prints the list from the beginning, to wherever the 7th element ended up after the list was sorted. The number of elements it prints therefore depends on the values in the list, of course.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::list<int> l;
    l.push_back(1);
    l.push_back(0);
    std::cout << (void*)(&*l.begin()) << "\n";
    l.sort();
    std::cout << (void*)(&*l.begin()) << "\n";
}
```

The two address printed differ, showing that (unlike `std::sort`), `std::list::sort` has sorted by changing the links between the elements, not by assigning new values to the elements.

I've always assumed that this is mandated (likewise for `reverse()`). I can't actually find explicit text to say so, but if you look at the description of `merge`, and consider that the reason for `list::sort` to exist is *presumably* because mergesort works nicely with lists, then I think it's "obviously" intended. `merge` says, "Pointers and references to the moved elements of x now refer to those same elements but as members of *this" (23.3.5.5./23), and the start of the section that includes `merge` and `sort` says, "Since lists allow fast insertion and erasing from the middle of a list, certain operations are provided specifically for them" (23.3.5.5/1).

Comment: @Orion: output looks plausible to me. Your `print` code prints up to (but not including) the last element printed during setup. In your example, that was 973452982, and the last value printed is somewhat smaller, 829465641. Try printing out the seed you used (so that your tests are repeatable) and printing out the whole list (so that you can see all the contents are and hence check whether or not it does what I say). It's certainly possible I missed something else in your code, that means there's more going on than just what I say.

Comment: @Orion: your loop in `print` breaks when `begin == end`, *without* printing the element referred to by `end` itself.

Comment: Ah, yes, quite right. That probably should have been more obvious to me.
So, iterator invalidation refers to a change in the element that iterator points to? I didn't really realize this.

Comment: @Orion: iterator invalidation means that you can no longer use the iterator at all (either dereference it or increment it etc). I think it's true for all standard containers, that there are no operations in which an iterator can remain valid but refer to an element at a different address from what it did before, but I'm not certain of that. If there is such an operation, then presumably it would invalidate pointers and references but *not* iterators to the old element.